# lxml : How to verify tag value in different nodes

Tags: python, lxml

I've the following xml (a part of .vcxproj in fact) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;ELEC_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>false</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      </AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>AdvancedVectorExtensions</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;ELEC_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <CompileAsManaged>
      </CompileAsManaged>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>false</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      </AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>StreamingSIMDExtensions2</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

And I want to verify each data of `ClCompile` or `Link`. I can get Element, but not a specific one and verify his value after.

Here is my actual code :

```
tree = etree.parse(xml)
ns = {'ns': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}

debug = tree.xpath('//ns:ItemDefinitionGroup[@Condition="\'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)\'==\'Release|x64\'"]', namespaces=ns)
for d in debug:
    print(d)
    for g in d:
        print(g)
```

And I have the following output :

```
<Element {http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}ClCompile at 0x7f95a2eb2548>
Level4
Create
MaxSpeed
true
true
WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;ELEC_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)


false


StreamingSIMDExtensions2
<Element {http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}Link at 0x7f95a2eb25c8>
Windows
true
true
true
No dependencies
```

Now I want to check if `Optimization` is `MaxSpeed` and do something after. But I can't. If I try :

```
tree.xpath('//ns:ItemDefinitionGroup[@Condition="\'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)\'==\'Release|x64\'"]/ClCompile/Optimization', namespaces=ns)
```

It returns an empty list.

How can I just check specially `Optimization`, for only `ItemDefinitionGroup` with `Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'"` ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: try [contains(@Condition,'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)\'==\'Release|Win32'')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the namespace for the other nodes also i.e `/ns:ClCompile/ns:Optimization` , using your sample data we get:

```
In [6]: import lxml.etree as et
In [7]: tree= et.parse("test.xml")

In [8]: ns = {'ns': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}

In [9]: opts = tree.xpath("""//ns:ItemDefinitionGroup[@Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'"]/ns:ClCompile/ns:Optimization""", namespaces=ns)


In [10]: opts
Out[10]: [<Element {http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}Optimization at 0x7f3849c0cb00>]

In [11]: opts[0].text
Out[11]: 'MaxSpeed'
```

If you wanted to also filter by MaxSpeed, you would change to :

```
/ns:ClCompile/ns:Optimization[text()='MaxSpeed']
```